# Define server IP globally

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, plist

I want to define a string variable which holds an IP Address globally,so that if in future the IPAddress got changed no need to go to each class file & update it, So for this what is the best way to implement whether to use **plist** or a **global macro class** or **.pch file** of my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a .h file. Say, GlobalMacros.h

In GlobalMacros.h

```
#define IP_ADDR @“SERVER_IP”
```

In your .pch file

```
import “GlobalMacros.h”
```

Now you can simply access the IP_ADDR anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just create NSObject class and then place your URL in it and then access it and use it where you want.

in h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Config : NSObject {

}

//configuration section... 
extern  NSString        *SiteURL;
extern  NSString        *SiteAPIURL;

@end
```

in .m

```
#import "Config.h"

@implementation Config
//live
NSString        *SiteURL                = @"http://yourIP/";
NSString        *SiteAPIURL             = @"http://yourIP/";

@end
```

in `Prefix.pch` just import it `#import "Config.h"`

and use it in the class where you want to use

```
NSString *apiURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@login.php",SiteAPIURL];
```

Comment: This is a quite oo-style suggestion. If you get a bit further and apply a signleton pattern here, then it would be really nice.

Answer (score 0):

.pch file if you would never change it.